# Como fazer o update de alguns campos de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, adonisjs

Estou usando o framework baseado em Java Scrit e NodeJs,AdonisJS.Preciso fazer o update de alguns campos em uma tabela.Os campos da tabela **user** precisam ser alterados,por padrão eles vem **NULLS**.
Os campos são *passwordResetToken*, *passwordResetExpires*

Meu controller:

```js
async forgotPassword({ request, response }) {
    const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    const { email } = request.body;

    try {
      const user = await User.find(email);    //.find({ email });
      const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
      const now = new Date();
      now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);                       //1 HR valid token

      // console.log(token)
      // console.log(now)

      await user.update({
        passwordResetToken: token,
        passwordResetExpires: now,
      });

      const msg = {
        to: email,
        from: env.SENDGRID_USE_EMAIL,                         //your e-mail register sendgrid
        subject: "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
        text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
        html: token,
        email,
        //'<strong>and easy to do anywhere fd, even with Node.js {token} </strong> {token}',
      };

      sgMail.send(msg);

      //res.send({ Successfully: true, user: req.token });
      console.log(sgMail);
      console.log(token);
      console.log(now);
      //console.log(error);

      res.status(200).json({
        Success: "Request sent successfully,check token in your email!",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400).send({ error: "E-mail does not exist!" });
      console.log(email);
    }
  }
```

O **Erro** retornado no console:

```
TypeError: user.update is not a function
    at UserController.forgotPassword (C:\SOFTWARE\singular_store\app\Controllers\Http\UserController.js:140:18)
    at async Server._routeHandler (C:\SOFTWARE\singular_store\node_modules\@adonisjs\framework\src\Server\index.js:121:25)
    at async AuthInit.handle (C:\SOFTWARE\singular_store\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\src\Middleware\AuthInit.js:60:5)
    at async ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.handle (C:\SOFTWARE\singular_store\app\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.js:14:5)
    at async BodyParser.handle (C:\SOFTWARE\singular_store\node_modules\@adonisjs\bodyparser\src\BodyParser\index.js:284:7)
```

Eu tentei várias vezes e não consegui,mesmo o erro estando na cara e bem descrito pelo Adonis.Tentei algumas alternativas sem sucesso.Eu acredito que o erro possa ser simples,de sintaxe ou algo que ainda não consigo enxergar.
Desde já grato a quem puder me ajudar!

Atenciosamente!
Guilherme Henrique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const { email } = request.body;
    try {
      //const { email } = request.body;
      const user = await User.findBy("email", email);
      const token = crypto.randomBytes(15).toString("hex");
      const now = new Date();
      now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1); //1 HR valid token


      if (user) {
        user.merge({
          passwordResetToken: token,
          passwordResetExpires: now,
        });

        //SAVE DATAS
        await user.save();
      }

      response.status(200).json({
        Success: "Request sent successfully,check token in your email!",
      });

    
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400).send({ error: "Fatal error try again" });
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

O que pode estar ocorrendo é que a a variável "user" tem o conteúdo retornado por " await User.find(email);"

```
const user = await User.find(email);
```

Se o usuário não for localizado, o "user" não vai o método update. Isso justifica o erro.

Uma forma de evitar a mensagem de erro seria verificar se "user" tem conteúdo antes de fazer o update.

```
if (user){ //Aqui foi feita a alteracao
  await user.update({
    passwordResetToken: token,
    passwordResetExpires: now,
  });
```

O código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
try {
      const user = await User.find(email);    //.find({ email });
      const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
      const now = new Date();
      now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);                       //1 HR valid token

      // console.log(token)
      // console.log(now)


      if (user){ //Aqui foi feita a alteracao
      await user.update({
        passwordResetToken: token,
        passwordResetExpires: now,
      });
}

      const msg = {
        to: email,
        from: env.SENDGRID_USE_EMAIL,                         //your e-mail register sendgrid
        subject: "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
        text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
        html: token,
        email,
        //'<strong>and easy to do anywhere fd, even with Node.js {token} </strong> {token}',
      };

      sgMail.send(msg);

      //res.send({ Successfully: true, user: req.token });
      console.log(sgMail);
      console.log(token);
      console.log(now);
      //console.log(error);

      res.status(200).json({
        Success: "Request sent successfully,check token in your email!",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400).send({ error: "E-mail does not exist!" });
      console.log(email);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Bins, eu estive com problemas nesse meio tempo.Mas voltarei a trabalhar nesse projeto e verificarei sua resposta ainda hoje.Atenciosamente